# SED Match Multiple Strings In ANY Text File Is Hanging And Not Completing

Tags: html, regex, linux, bash, sed

I am using the following code to replace lines that match string1 or string2. It has been working fine normally on html text. (I know that using regex and html is frowned upon.) However, on one particular file, it does not work.

I have tried ensuring proper end of lines and double checking the code. I can't share the actual file other than it has lots of html lines.

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/.*\(string1\|string2\).*/match/'
```

Using the details provided and without the file, can you see any reason from this command to hang? Your insight is greatly appreciated.

Update:

Here are some other ideas:

- Could leading white spaces or blank lines cause it?
- Could it be a large bracket or special character causing it?
- There's something causing SED to hang, have any similar experience?
- Could it be an extremely long line that causes SED to hang?

**Update 2:**

I figured out that there is one massive long line - 494,000 characters. The line is mostly CSS code and details.

Now, I guess the question is...Is it just the long line or is it a character within that line?

Comment: Can you use node? If so, you can use `document.querySelector`.

Comment: I mean, I guess I could, but I would really prefer to use straight sed, awk or other bash commands.

Comment: Fair enough, can you provide us with an example part of your HTML file then?

Comment: tried using ``g`` at the end of the regex ?

Comment: Even if I did provide a sample, it would probably work just fine. The file is huge and contains a lot of html lines and possibly garbled code so something must be causing it to hang :-/

Comment: Hey @terminalninja, yea, just tried it with the same result. Could it be caused by a large bracket `}` in the file or something like that?

Comment: You were using the wrong brackets. ``sed 's/.*[string1\|string2].*/match/'`` This works with files with white spaces.

Comment: Hey @terminalninja, nice idea, but didn't work. I think I'm getting somewhere close to which line is causing the issue. Might be a massively long line?

Comment: Massive lines doesn't matter for sed. Could you provide a snippet of the file with a matching section ?

Comment: Okay, so I figured out that there is one massive long line - 494,000 characters. Now, I guess the question is...Is it just the long line or is it a character within that line?

Comment: Just wanna know will happen if you do a `sed "s/\(string1\|string2\).*|./match/g"` ?

Comment: With your own regex engine consumes all ~490K characters at the first step and in an average case falls into backtracking immediately. If `string1` is placed in beginning of the line (worst case) then engine backtracks ~`490000 * 2` times, where `2` is the number of branches. My proposed regex aimed to reduce this number of backtracks drastically.

Comment: Actually, this runs through the file but it does not work. See my answer below for correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat embarrassed to be providing this answer, but I did really spend time troubleshooting the issue and working with you guys. Hopefully, if anyone has an issue with SED hanging, then they will find this helpful:

One line in the file contained over 400K characters, causing SED to hang for an excessively long time. This was the issue. Once the line was shortened, it took less time to process. This can be fixed using the following command to shorten the lines first, then run:

```
cat file.txt | awk 'length($0)<1000' | sed 's/.*\(string1\|string2\).*/match/'
```

This will solve your issue if matching anything with a SED command and it's just hanging.

(Will update the question title to reflect this).

Comment: Did you test the input in smaller lines with something like `cat file.txt | fold -w 1000 | sed ...` ? Does sed work fast on the parts of the long line? How are string1/string2 filled? Are the variables that may have a / inside?

Comment: Hi Walter, yes, sed works fast on parts of the long line. String1/2 need to be replaced on the line, but in this case, the line over 1K characters is irrelevant. And, nope, they are not variables. Thanks for the questions :-)